# Location.href não está me transferindo de página no ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou fazendo uma tela de login em ASP.NET MVC. O framework faz todos os processos completos sem erros: vai ao banco, consulta o login e volta com um OK (usuário existe, posso autenticar). Quando o fluxo volta do banco e passa pelo `if (dados.OK)`, ele tem que me jogar para outra página, mas isso não está acontecendo: simplesmente o navegador executa o código e não me joga para a outra página (`_ViewStart`)

O que pode ser?
Um forma melhor?
Dicas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#status").hide();
$("#btLogar").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        data: { Login: $("#txtLogin").val(), Senha: $("#txtSenha").val() },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Login/AutenticarLogin",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#status").html("Estamos autenticando o usuário... Só um instante.");
            $("#status").show();
        },
        success: function (dados) {
            if (dados.OK) {
                $("#status").html(dados.Mensagem)
                setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "_ViewStart" }, 5000);
                alert("logado");
                $("#status").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#status").html(dados.Mensagem);
                $("#status").show();
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#status").html(dados.Mensagem);
            $("#status").show()
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Comece vendo e postando o botão de btLogar,

Comment: Não entendi....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente, há muita coisa errada aqui.

`_ViewStart` não é uma *View* representada por uma rota. Portanto, ela não pode ser chamada pelo JS.

Uma rota de autenticação de login **jamais** deveria ser `GET`. `GET` é um método para passar parâmetros por URL. Como é um formulário, o método correto deveria ser `POST`.

Não sei como está a lógica de autenticação, mas creio que não haja definição de cookies ou objetos de segurança que bloqueiem o usuário quando ele tenta acessar qualquer outra rota do seu sistema.

Ainda assim, se você quer mesmo continuar nesta abordagem, o correto seria:

```
setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "/Home" }, 5000);
```